# Looking for a tailwind css utility class to automatically split a text in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tailwind-css

I am using wordpress and tailwind-css. To automatically split a text/paragraph currently i add a custom class to this wordpress element (in my case: cols). The code for this class is:

```
p.cols
  column-count: 2
  column-gap: 20px
```

This works fine, but i would rather use a tailwind utility class. Is there any chance to do this with tailwind?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution in tailwindcss v3. Here you can use columns-[n].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).